# Dividing fractions by fractions, understanding reciprocals and simply dividing. Help?

Tags: proof-verification, arithmetic

so maybe you guys can help me identify a flaw in my logic (none of which i am capable of explaining it's intuition right now) and maybe you can help me identify what I want to know. Something I don't understand, and I'm unsure about what it is.

4/6th divided by 1/2
I made 1/2 into 3/6, i felt like it would be "easier" to work with those numbers, logic unidentified.

So 3/6 goes into 4/6 once. A 3rd of 3/6 is 1/6, which is the difference between 3/6 and 4/6. If i add that 6th then we have the number which makes 4/6, since 3/6 is .5 and 1/6 (used a calculator, which im upset about) is .16666 theyre equal.

So i dont know if i totally understand that, if you gave me other fractions i don't know if id always be able to solve them with my method.  maybe i would. Anyway, i don't see how this relates to reciprocals, how they were figured out, and what operation is done to make a fraction a reciprocal. they look arbitrary to me.

can someone explain the logic? thanks!

Comment: so what's your answer ?

Comment: the logic is that a reciprocal should multiply with the original value to equal a fraction equal to 1.

Comment: The answer is 1 and 1/3rd roddy. which is 4/3. The reciprocal times the original equating to 1 doesn't explain why i get 4/3 when i do 4/6 * 6/3 simplified, well it's not obvious to me.

Comment: because ${8\over 6}={4\over 3}$ they are equivalent fractions. for your altered version it's simply cancellation. to irreducible form.

Comment: I must be retarded. I don't see the relevance of the reciprocal times the original number equaling 1. So 1 represents a whole, the two fractions dividing each other balance out to 1 becuase of their equal differences or what ever. I seriously feel incredibly unintelligent it sucks.

Comment: a fraction of fractions is equivalent to the numerator fraction times the reciprocal of the denominator fraction.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dividing+fractions